# Understanding abstract superclass NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

I am reading some book about `objective C` ,and they say there that `NSNumber` is an `abstract` `superclass` of many `subclasses` that we can use .

So, "when we call a method in `NSNumber`, the appropriate subclass is used" .

This is not going with some other rule that i know :

if `superclass A`, has `subclass B` , and you calling a method in the **super class A** , that is in the **subclass B**, you can't do that- because inheritance is working all the way up and not down.

So, how is that the `superclass (abstract) class- NSNumber`, is using its `subclass` methods ??

What is the hierarchy here ?

Thanks .

Comment: i guess you are reading S.Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C" =). Cool beginner tutorial, but some technology concepts tied to Objective-C are missing, and some technology concepts are described a bit too broad.

Comment: Yes thats what i am reading :) i know that , i am developing for a few years, and i just wanted to go over things again .

Comment: This is wrong: "if superclass A, has subclass B , and you calling a method in the super class A , that is in the subclass B, you can't do that", or at least a misinterpretation.  You may call a method NAMED in the superclass, but you always get the method that is present in the subclass that represents the actual object, if there is such a method in the subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done through [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) pattern.
From documentation:

> The abstract superclass in a class cluster must declare methods for
>   creating instances of its private subclasses. It’s the superclass’s
>   responsibility to dispense an object of the proper subclass based on
>   the creation method that you invoke—you don’t, and can’t, choose the
>   class of the instance.

Whenever you create number with some factory method, like `+numberWithInt:` the factory returns instance of concrete subclass. Afterwards, when you call something like `-stringValue:` this selector is sent to instance of concrete `NSNumber` subclass - int in this case.
So, `NSNumber` factory methods actually does not return `NSNumber` objects - they return concrete subclasses. Same is true for other Cocoa class clusters - `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`.

Comment: To clarify Petro's (correct) answer, the assertion "when we call a method in NSNumber, the appropriate subclass is used" is true ONLY for the methods that create NSNumbers, other methods are just sent to the private subclass you end up with.

Comment: Okay, we can correct thet assertion by adding simple word `factory`. "when we call a <missing>`factory`</missing> method in NSNumber, the appropritate subclass is used" =)

Comment: thanks, so when you say return an object, that means that the NSNmuber class is allocating an object of one of its subclasses ? i can't really imagine whats going on there.

Comment: >> The abstract superclass in a class cluster must declare methods for creating instances of its private subclasses. It’s the superclass’s responsibility to dispense an object of the proper subclass based on the creation method that you invoke—you don’t, and can’t, choose the class of the instance.

Answer (score 2):

In effect there are classes NSDoubleNumber, NSLongLongNumber, NSIntegerNumber, etc, (made-up names) and you get the appropriate one.  But as with all subclassing, if you then call a method of the object via it's superclass type it will respond, invoking the class-specific method appropriate to that instance.

Objective-C muddles things slightly, since if you ask what the class is it won't return "NSDoubleNumber" or whatever but instead returns an essentially meaningless name for the whole cluster, or for a particular subdivision of it.

The point is, you can treat the instances as objects of the single fictitious class "NSNumber" and never need to worry about which subclass you actually have.

(BTW, similar things are true of NSArray, NSDictionary, and a number of other classes.)

Comment: is there any proof for names you just used (`NSDoubleNumber`, `NSLongLongNumber` etc)? i mean, `NSLog`'ging of both [@(1.25f) class] and [@(1) class] will give the same result `__NSCFNumber`. Moreover, they have the same `isa` pointer so it seems they are implemented like some composite objects... Just interesting to get the names' source.

Comment: @PetroKorienev - No, I made those up, for exposition.  The real names are hidden.

Comment: THANKS , but i don't get what you said.. i can't imagine the actual hierarchy, can you give me a simple example on what happen when i call some method from nsnumber?

Comment: @Curnelious - Understand that with *any* subclass of *any* superclass, when you call a method the subclass is first checked to see if it implements the method, and only if the subclass does not is the superclass method invoked.  This is true whether the type of the variable addressing the object is "MySubclass" or "MySuperclass" -- the determining factor is the object itself, not the pointer addressing it.